# PHP success of if statement pass to new file

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, error-handling

I'm having trouble with my register form which uses PHP and SQL.

The actual database stuff works fine. So does the error reporting. The problem is with the successful completion of the form.

If you go here and type in bad data/no data into the form you will see the error reporting comes back ok:
http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/register-form.php

However, if you put in all the fields (a long username, long password and tick the box) and hit "make my account" I need it to reroute to `register-success.php`

No matter what I change the success statement to it won't work. It always reroutes you back to `register-form.php` but with no error messages.

This is the register function with all the validation:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require 'functions.php';

    if(isset($_POST['sign-up'])){
    // username
        if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'] = $username;

        if(strlen($username) > 3){
            if(strlen($username) < 31){
                if(user_exists($username) === true){
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'That username is already taken. Sorry, please try again with a different username.';
                } else{
                // passed
                // continue
                }
                } else {
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is greater than 30 characters.';
                }
                    } else {
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is less than 3 characters.';
                }
                    } else {
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is not entered.';}

        if (isset($_POST['password'])){
                $password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
                    if(strlen($password) >= 8){
            $password = hash_function($password);
            } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Your secret password is too short. You should make a password with at least 8 letters.";
            }} 
else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You haven't put in a password.";}

            // Email address
            if (!empty($_POST['email_address'])){
                $email_address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email_address']));
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'] = $email_address;
                if(strlen($email_address) > 10){ // email address less than 10
                    if(strlen($email_address) < 161){ // if longer than 160
                                    if(email_valid($email_address) == false){ // email address invalid format
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address has been put in wrong. Please check and try again.";
                    }
                    else{
                    // passed min length, passed max length, passed validation
                    // Continue
                    }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The email address is too long.';}
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address is too short. It can't be shorter than 10 letters.";
                    }
            }
            else{// passed (no email input)
            }

            if (isset($_POST['tos'])){
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['tos'] = $_POST['tos'];
                if(empty($_SESSION['status']['register']['error'])){
                    if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

                    // Sends an email
                    send_email($email_address);

                    // Reroutes to success page
                    header('Location: register-success.php');

                    } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    die();
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Something went wrong. We're sorry. Please try again.";
                    }
                } else 
{
}
            } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You have to agree to the House Rules to be able to sign up.";
            }

            header('Location: register-form.php');
        } else {
        }

    ?>
```

Edit: As the correct answer didn't supply the code, here it is for future reference. The issue was conflicting redirects. So now there is a wrapper if statement so they do not conflict.

To the success section I added a check for a variable:

```
if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

                    // Sends an email
                    send_email($email_address);
                    // Reroute to success page
                    $succeeded = true;
                    header('Location: register-success.php');

                }
```

Then, I only enacted the final redirect if the success variable was false.

```
// If postback needed
        if($succeeded != true){
        header('Location: register-form.php');
        }
```

Comment: Props for sharing the website with us.  I would have skipped over this question if I hadn't been able to try it myself :)

Comment: @DanFarrell no worries I always do but I have to say sometimes people remove it because they don't think its necessary. But I always feel it's best to show it. You can see for yourself the error messages work fine. You will even see that putting your email in and everything correct sends you an email. But you will never be rerouted to success.php....

Comment: You've got a lot of syntax errors anyways, unless it's the wonky indentation. you can't have `else {...} else {...}`

Comment: @MarcB soz that was me trying to make it more readable for SO. It's on dif lines in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the issue is this:

The `if(register(...))` block is firing fine, but there's nothing *stopping* the writing out of `header('Location: register-form.php');` on success. You're essentially rewriting your first redirect (on success) with your second (back to `register-form.php`)

A possible solution would be to add a flag you threw on success and wrap that final redirect in an `if(!$succeeded)` or something.  But all these `if` blocks put together is prone to just this type of error.  I highly recommend you use a different system.  If I were writing this page I would probably collect each error in a separate if block, clearing them out if there was no error - and then on the basis of whether there were any error messages, control the redirect at the end.  The flatter your conditional hierarchy, the easier it will be to debug.

Comment: Can you explain how I can debug this? I can see that your registration has worked just fine (marmiteboy) but I am not sure why this is not passing the test. Especially if you put an email address in too... it DOES pass all the data to the DB.

Comment: Within that code also lies the email function send. So it must be running that function otherwise you wouldn't receive an email.

Comment: yep, you're right, my first analysis was flawed.  Better answer.

Comment: This is what I had an inkling it might be. They are conflicting. It's running success but then it's also running register-form.php. How would I go about restructuring my code so that it never runs the second redirect if register block is run?

Comment: I added a bit of a suggestion to my post.  Basically, flatten your `if` structure.

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank you. I will update the OP with my code change so it can stay here for reference and you can add it to your answer, I will mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Dan that the if statements should be flattened, that's no reason for it not to redirect. If the email function is firing, then the header should be set. The problem isn't the if structure. The issue is that it exits the if structure and sees, `header('Location: register-form.php');` Previously it was:

```
if(){
   if(){
     // a few more if statements.
     header("Locaiton: register-success.php");
   }else{
     die();
   }
}else{

}
header("Location: register-form.php");
```

it was setting "register-success.php" as the location and then executing the rest of the code. It then (when it exited the if statement) saw `Location: register-form.php` and overwrote the previous value to navigate to success. By adding an `exit();` call after you set the location to "register-success", the code will not overwrite it. I have also added the variable true to the header call to set success as the header and "303". True is added so it can in fact overwrite any previous value that was set for location and "303" was added due to the fact that it seemed more fitting to have it redirect with the HTTP code for `see other` rather than `found`.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['sign-up'])){
    /*

        CHECK USERNAME

    */
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'] = $username;

        if(strlen($username) > 3){
            if(strlen($username) < 31){
                if(user_exists($username) === true){
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'That username is already taken. Sorry, please try again with a different username.';
                } else{
                    // passed
                    // continue
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is greater than 30 characters.';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is less than 3 characters.';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is not entered.';
    }
    /*

        CHECK PASSWORD

    */
    if (isset($_POST['password'])){
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
        if(strlen($password) >= 8){
            $password = hash_function($password);
        }else{
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Your secret password is too short. You should make a password with at least 8 letters.";
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You haven't put in a password.";
    }
    /*

        CHECK email

    */
    if (!empty($_POST['email_address'])){
        $email_address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email_address']));
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'] = $email_address;
        if(strlen($email_address) > 10){ // email address less than 10
            if(strlen($email_address) < 161){ // if longer than 160
                if(email_valid($email_address) == false){ // email address invalid format
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address has been put in wrong. Please check and try again.";
                }else{
                    // passed min length, passed max length, passed validation
                    // Continue
                }
            }else{
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The email address is too long.';}
        }else{
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address is too short. It can't be shorter than 10 letters.";
        }
    }else{
        // passed (no email input)
    }
    /*

        CHECK TOS

    */
    if(isset($_POST['tos'])){
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['tos'] = $_POST['tos'];
        if(empty(($_SESSION['status']['register']['error']))){
            if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){
                // Sends an email
                send_email($email_address);

                // Reroutes to success page
                header('Location: register-success.php', true, "303");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo mysql_error();
                die();
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Something went wrong. We're sorry. Please try again.";
            }
        }else{
            // do nothing
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You have to agree to the House Rules to be able to sign up.";
    }
    header('Location: register-form.php');
} else {
    // nothing
}
?>
```